# Email template preview gives 500

Tags: magento2, email-templates, nginx

In my server, I am using Nginx and issue which I faced is when we have long data in the email template. while preview that template we get 500 and page is completely broken. In this case, this is not even hitting the magento controller.

Is there some Nginx server configuration is missing, please let me know.

Comment: Any error in your server log file

Comment: no, there is no information in the log file.